# Can a tangent vector extend to a vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $p\in M$. I would like to know whether any tangent vector $X_p \in T_pM$ extends to a vector field over $M$.

If so is it unique? How can I construct it?

Comment: Take a bump function, with support in a small ball centered on your point, and multiply it by the constant vector field (value $X_p$)... this has fixed points outside of your ball.

Comment: (This construction clearly shows it is not unique -- add random bump functions)

Comment: Where "constant vector field" means constant in some coordinate system on the ball, of course.

Answer (score 5):

First notice that this problem is easy when you're in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then use a small coordinate patch and a bump function to extend the vector field as you wish.